# Laravel 5.5 add folder in Resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am using Resources for my API..

> What I am trying to do

I want to setup my **Resources folder like this:**

Resources/Category/And_My_Category_Resources_Here

> What I have done

I have already made that folder and pointed to it in my controller like this:

```
use App\Http\Resources\Category\CategoryStore;
use App\Http\Resources\Category\CategoryStoreError;
```

But this got me error because I have added `Category folder`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to change the namespace in each Resource class:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources\Category;
```

You can let Laravel do it for you. When you're creating a new Resource class, add `Category/` to resource class name:

```
php artisan make:resource Category/CategoryStore
```

Comment: OMG HOW STUPID I AM!
thanks..
Is that a good practice to create many Resources for each request?

Comment: I will accept the answer now but I have to wait 8 min

Comment: Is that a good practice to add many Resources for each request?

Comment: @DOEE well, I don't think it's a good idea to add resource class if you just need to return an error or something. But I don't see anything bad in using many Resource classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was helpfull